# ENS: Can a contract own an ENS name?

Tags: ens

Can a contract own an ENS name? That would make it possibly to lock names for a period of time, making them immutable, so that the name can be trusted to continue to point to a certain contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an Ethereum Contract can have an ENS address.

From the [ENS documentation](http://ens.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#ens-in-5-minutes):

> The owner of a domain may be either an external account (a user) or a smart contract. A registrar is simply a smart contract that owns a domain, and issues subdomains of that domain to users that follow some set of rules defined in the contract.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can - I looked into this when i was learning about creating subdomains. The smart contract can own the ens, and it will also expire in the same way as it would if owned by a normal wallet address.